# Varnish (or Squid?) as an accellerator between Liferay and Alfresco

Tags: squid, cache, varnish, alfresco

We have a Liferay installation for a corporate (internal) portal and we are using Alfresco as a back-end for the CMS part.

Most Liferay pages include one or more portlet that query Alfresco to generate content (usually as links to an actual document in Alfresco). While the portlet are dynamic (in the sense that they have to query AlFresco to find the "current" list of items/topics/articles) the actual result of the queries may remain constant for a bit (maybe an hour, maybe more).

In order to speed things up I am considering setting up some sort of webcaching mechanism between Liferay and Alfresco. I am thinking of Varnish (and possibly Squid). Anyone can provide pointers, experiences, suggestions or alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented the same thing for one of our client, Earlier we had the same approach but found difficult to integrate the Varnish cache with liferay , So we added the Caching framework at Service layer and cache the alfresco content, And accessed the content VIA Java
web api.